# Enum *seems* to be initialized more than once, the constructor is called more than once. If I’m right, then why?

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, enums, singleton

I’m reading thru this tutorial:

[JAX-RS Delete Example](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jax-rs/delete-example.html)

It first runs: `ClientAllOrders()`, which creates 5 orders. Then it runs: `ClientDeleteById()`, which deletes orders 2 and 4. Then it runs `ClientAllOrders()`, and gets all orders except for orders 2, 4. It creates orders here:

```
public enum OrderService {
    Instance;
    private Map<Integer, Order> orders = new HashMap<>();

    OrderService() {
        Instant instant = OffsetDateTime.now().toInstant();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            Order order = new Order();
            order.setId(i);
            order.setItem("item " + i);
            order.setQty((int) (1 + Math.random() * 100));
            long millis = instant.minus(Period.ofDays(i))
                                 .toEpochMilli();
            order.setOrderDate(new Date(millis));
            orders.put(i, order);
        }
    }
//---
}
```

Note that `OrderResource` is not a `Singleton`, so by default a new instance of the resource class is created for each new request, however, the `OrderService.constructor` is called only ones and `Enum` in initialized only once as expected.

The above scenario results in this output:

```
// ClientAllOrders:

Order{id=1, item='item 1', qty=62, orderDate=Fri Jul 24 18:27:51 EDT 2020}
Order{id=2, item='item 2', qty=100, orderDate=Thu Jul 23 18:27:51 EDT 2020}
Order{id=3, item='item 3', qty=29, orderDate=Wed Jul 22 18:27:51 EDT 2020}
Order{id=4, item='item 4', qty=28, orderDate=Tue Jul 21 18:27:51 EDT 2020}
Order{id=5, item='item 5', qty=28, orderDate=Mon Jul 20 18:27:51 EDT 2020}

// ClientDeleteById – deletes orders 2 and 4:

true
true

// Run ClientAllOrders again:

Order{id=1, item='item 1', qty=62, orderDate=Fri Jul 24 18:27:51 EDT 2020}
Order{id=3, item='item 3', qty=29, orderDate=Wed Jul 22 18:27:51 EDT 2020}
Order{id=5, item='item 5', qty=28, orderDate=Mon Jul 20 18:27:51 EDT 2020}
```

However, if I add this line in `ClientAllOrders`:

```
Collection<Order> c = OrderService.Instance.getAllOrders();
c.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Then `OrderService.constructor` is called again, and the map now has 5 new orders in it. Why unlike the `REST` requests that all share the same `Enum` object, here, `Enum` was initialized again and the `constructor()` was called again creating 5 new orders?

```
    public class ClientAllOrders {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            
            //get all  orders
            WebTarget allOrderTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/jaxrs-delete-example/orders");
    
            Response response = allOrderTarget.request().get();
            List<Order> orders = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Order>>() {});
            System.out.println("Orders by REST call:");
            orders.forEach(System.out::println);
            
// Added this line - Enum is initialized again and constructor called again, creating new orders:
            Collection<Order> c = OrderService.Instance.getAllOrders();
            System.out.println("Orders created again:");
            c.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
```

This is the output if I run `ClientAllOrders`, note the orders created are different:

```
Orders by REST call:
Order{id=1, item='item 1', qty=59, orderDate=Fri Jul 24 18:35:24 EDT 2020}
Order{id=2, item='item 2', qty=14, orderDate=Thu Jul 23 18:35:24 EDT 2020}
Order{id=3, item='item 3', qty=78, orderDate=Wed Jul 22 18:35:24 EDT 2020}
Order{id=4, item='item 4', qty=3, orderDate=Tue Jul 21 18:35:24 EDT 2020}
Order{id=5, item='item 5', qty=2, orderDate=Mon Jul 20 18:35:24 EDT 2020}

Orders created again:
Order{id=1, item='item 1', qty=1, orderDate=Fri Jul 24 18:35:24 EDT 2020}
Order{id=2, item='item 2', qty=53, orderDate=Thu Jul 23 18:35:24 EDT 2020}
Order{id=3, item='item 3', qty=76, orderDate=Wed Jul 22 18:35:24 EDT 2020}
Order{id=4, item='item 4', qty=31, orderDate=Tue Jul 21 18:35:24 EDT 2020}
Order{id=5, item='item 5', qty=25, orderDate=Mon Jul 20 18:35:24 EDT 2020}
```

Comment: The real question is why OrderService is declared as an enum. That's a total misunderstanding of the concept of "enumeration".

Comment: @user13784117 A popular book (by a Java architect, I think) recommends creating an enum with a single value as a “trick” for implementing a singleton.  (Personally I prefer to do it the slightly longer, but less cryptic, way:   private constructor, static factory method with synchronization.)

Comment: Appalling!  (but thanks for the enlightenment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client and the server run in separate processes, in separate JVMs, independently. The server has one version of `enum OrderService`, and the client has another. Nothing links these two instances of the enum to each other.

In your case, the "server" is an application server, where you deploy the web application "war" archive. The "client" is a separate Java program with a `main` method. that you run from your IDE with the "run as Java application" action.

Comment: Sorry... don't understand the concept of separate JVMs, I am running the whole thing locally and have only one JVM running... what am I missing?

Comment: When you run the server with `mvn tomcat7:run-war` (from the article you link to) that's one jvm. When you run the client that has the main method, that's a different jvm.

Comment: I don't run it the way it mentioned in the article, I create the war, deploy it on server, start the server and then only run the ClientAllOrders.main() method, does it still considered two JVM? We have two threads (processes): one that runs the REST services and the main() thread - the one running inside main() method - are these threads run in separate JVM?

Comment: I run like: main(): Run As: Java Application

Comment: Yes, the server where you deploy a war is one jvm process, and selecting "run as Java application" in the IDE starts another jvm process

Comment: Then why Run As Java Application, which is one JVM process, is not considered the same process for both REST services and the other OrderService Instance? Asking b/c these two are part of the same main() method and looks to me part of same JVM process… sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you ever got to respond above, would you also clarify the concept of client and server here? Perhaps I’m confused by server and client here as its all one local machine.

Comment: The "client" sends a request using REST to the "server", and the "server" replies. REST request/reponse is one way programs can share information between each other, and it works whether "client" and "server" are on the same machine or on different machines and on opposite sides of the globe.